# SHA256 of block header _hexadecimal vs string

Tags: string, hash, blockchain, bitcoin, sha

I am new to blockchain and don't have an IT background.

Trying to understand the technique of SHA256 of block header component/paramters (i.e previous hash, merkel rule, difficulity level..etc) when appended together.

I noticed that most online SHA256 accepts only string (or text) as input. Thus, i am unable to verify the Block hash using combined block paramters, which are in hex, in these SHA256. There is some online converter which accept hex decimal entry. But since i already have a macro XML request established to one of the online SHA256 text converter, i am wondering if there is any way that i can convert the block hex parameters into string first then use that string into into SHA256 text converter and of course get the same result.

I also understand some hex-decimal character are control character (e.g 00,01..etc) and may not be converted into string. I just wanted to confirm that ? Please note I am not looking into any decoding in any programming language just want to know if a conversion is possible/ correct approach and if yes, what process/method should be followed?

Example, genesis block with appended parameters of 0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003ba3edfd7a7b12b27ac72c3e67768f617fc81bc3888a51323a9fb8aa4b1e5e4a29ab5f49ffff001d1dac2b7c  >>> whether this can be converted into text/string.

Many thanks

Comment: sha256 operates on bytes, and because not every byte value is a displayable character there must be some way for the sha256 tool to accommodate arbitrary byte sequences. Presenting the input as hex-encoded bytes is common, as is base64 encoding. If you've an online sha256 tool that accepts hex-encoded input then you can use that. If you have a text string then you must decide how to convert that to bytes. Modern standards specify UTF-8. If you can find an online tool that accepts text characters and returns hex-encoded UTF-8 output then that's what you can provide as input to the SHA256 tool.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. there was a part in my question that has not been answered i am afraid. can (and is this a correct approach?) i ALWAYS convert the hexdecimal into text and then use the output text into SHA256 that accepts text and get the same result had i  used sha256 on the original Hexdecimal input? my main concern is mainly on the non printable character of the hex when converting into text ?

Comment: No, you cannot always do that. Only a sha256 tool that accepts hex-encoded or base64-encoded bytes can be used.

Comment: thanks alot , appreciated